# Can't scrape text with cheerio

Tags: node.js, reactjs, web-scraping, cheerio

i'm trying to scrape this page with cheerio https://en.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%B6%94%EC%9B%8C%EC%9A%94&range=all
But i can't get anything. I tried to get that 'Word-Idiom' text but i get nothing as response.

[image]

Here's my code

```
app.get("/conjugation", (req, res) => {
  axios(
    "https://en.dict.naver.com/#/search?query=%EC%B6%94%EC%9B%8C%EC%9A%94&range=all"
  )
    .then((response) => {
      const htmlData = response.data;
      const $ = cheerio.load(htmlData);
      const element = $(
        "#searchPage_entry > h3 > span.title_text.myScrollNavQuick.my_searchPage"
      );
      console.log(element.text());
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The server at that URL doesn't return any body DOM structure in the HTML response. The body DOM is rendered by linked JavaScript after the response is received. **Cheerio doesn't execute the JavaScript in the HTML response, so it won't be possible to scape that page using Cheerio**. Instead, you'll need to use another method which can execute the in-page JavaScript (e.g. [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)).

Comment: Is there some trick when using Puppeteer? Because i tried it and i get the same thing. I launch puppeteer, go to the page and then i fetch the result like this 
 `let result = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return Array.from(
      document.querySelector(
        "#searchPage_entry > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > a > strong"
      )
    );
  });`

Comment: @JoséCarlos That’s not enough code to debug. You can [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) which includes code that is a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and you’ll be much more likely to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue while web scraping, the page loads dynamically, that's why when you fetch the content of the initial get response from that website, all you're getting is script tags, print the `htmlData` so you can see what I mean. There are no loaded html elements in your response, what you'll have to do is use something like [selenium](https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver) to wait for the elements that you're requiring to get rendered.