# How to scrape video url using puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I'm trying to scrape video url of Instagram videos using puppeteer but unable to do it. it is returning null as a response

here is my code

```
async function getVideo(){
  const launch = await puppeteer.launch({headless: true});
  const page = await launch.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/p/CfW5u5UJmny/?hl=en');
  const video = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelector('video').src;
  });

  console.log(video); returns null

  await launch.close();
}
```

example ur: https://instagram.fluh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t50.16885-16/290072800_730588251588660_5005285215058589375_n.mp4?efg=eyJ2ZW5jb2RlX3RhZyI6InZ0c192b2RfdXJsZ2VuLjcyMC5pZ3R2LmJhc2VsaW5lIiwicWVfZ3JvdXBzIjoiW1wiaWdfd2ViX2RlbGl2ZXJ5X3Z0c19vdGZcIl0ifQ&_nc_ht=instagram.fluh1-1.fna.fbcdn.net&_nc_cat=100&_nc_ohc=ROJWkaOqkQcAX_z-_Ls&edm=AP_V10EBAAAA&vs=440468611258459_2442386419&_nc_vs=HBksFQAYJEdPQW9TaEUwaURaVmQ1Z0NBTC0yRkV0aVdIWkZidlZCQUFBRhUAAsgBABUAGCRHTEdvVHhGMWFjUUpsMzhDQUZNT0c1cV8wT3c1YnZWQkFBQUYVAgLIAQAoABgAGwGIB3VzZV9vaWwBMRUAACaa%2BO%2FYnLPeQBUCKAJDMywXQCDdsi0OVgQYEmRhc2hfYmFzZWxpbmVfMV92MREAdewHAA%3D%3D&ccb=7-5&oh=00_AfCBrACQlXOqmbGSWRk_6Urv_fmHJUFDIt-8w6EO0_UcHQ&oe=638D6CBD&_nc_sid=4f375e

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't scrape text with cheerio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72835426/cant-scrape-text-with-cheerio)

Comment: No, it didn't answer my question! As you suggested in my last question, that cheerio wouldn't work for websites like Instagram @jsejcksn

Comment: So I had to go with puppeteer

Comment: In my testing, Instagram uses a [`blob:` URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) for its video sources. I'm not saying that it's impossible to get the video data (it's not), but you're going to have to be a bit more enterprising or use the [official API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/reference/media).

Comment: this did the job for me document.querySelector('video').src; able to fetch the video url :) @jsejcksn

Comment: I was also getting the blob url when I executed it inside the browser console but when I run the same querySelector through puppeteer (inside page evaluate), it returns me the video url without blob @jsejcksn

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668394/how-to-scrape-video-url-using-puppeteer?noredirect=1#comment131794158_74668394) That's interesting information. Can you provide an example URL that you obtained using that method? Two unique ones would be even better so we can analyze variable qualities.

Comment: @jsejcksn What does cheerio have to do with this question? OP is using Puppeteer.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668394/how-to-scrape-video-url-using-puppeteer?noredirect=1#comment131794374_74668394) @ggorlen That's a stale comment (I prefer not to delete comments on this site).

Comment: Sure but unable to put the url in the comment because it is too long (restricted by stackoverflow) @jsejcksn

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668394/how-to-scrape-video-url-using-puppeteer?noredirect=1#comment131794546_74668394) @shaktigoyal You can update your question and provide them as examples to improve the detail of your question.

Comment: done! placed it at the bottom of question! check it @jsejcksn

Comment: at the end, I achieved the desired result :) I'm wondering how did I received the url without blob. Any idea? @jsejcksn

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74668394/how-to-scrape-video-url-using-puppeteer?noredirect=1#comment131794687_74668394) @shaktigoyal I'm glad that you reached your goal . I'm not sure how to respond to that single URL: more analysis is needed. I suspect that other people have already [analyzed](https://www.google.com/search?q=instagram+video+url+query+parameters) the video URL query parameters. For example, it appears that the `_nc_vs` param is a string in base64 format. Here's a fiddle that decodes them for you to view/edit/experiment: https://jsfiddle.net/cwatr7zv/

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the Instagram page. Since it takes a little while to load, I used setTimeout function to wait. Puppeteer also has many inbuilt functions you can use to obtain the src, such as the following.

```js
async function getVideo(){
  const launch = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await launch.newPage();
  await page.goto('https://www.instagram.com/p/CfW5u5UJmny/?hl=en');
  setTimeout(async () => {
    let src = await page.$eval("video", n => n.getAttribute("src"))
    console.log(src);
    await launch.close();
  }, 1000)
}
```

Comment: Node now has a promise API for setTimeout so you could use that rather than the callback version: `import {setTimeout} from 'timers/promises';`. That said, much better to use `waitForSelector` or `waitForFunction` rather than a sleep.

Comment: Thanks @ggorlen. For more information please refer puppeteer official documentation.
https://pptr.dev/api/

Comment: More info about what? Officially Puppeteer [doesn't recommennd using sleeps in any form](https://serpapi.com/blog/puppeteer-antipatterns/#overusing-waitfortimeout).

Comment: didn't work! Throwing the following error now "Session closed. Most likely the page has been closed." @MohamedRafiqP

Comment: waitForSelector worked for me! Thank you @ggorlen